# How to enable -Wunused-variable with -Wall?

Tags: c++, g++, c++14, gcc-warning

I am using the following command to build C++14.

```
g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
```

How to add the `-Wunused-variable` to the above line so that all warnings except `-Wunused-variable` are shown?

Comment: So you're looking to *disable* rather than enable `-Wunused-variable`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options):

> You can request many specific warnings with options beginning with ‘`-W`’, for example `-Wimplicit` to request warnings on implicit declarations. Each of these specific warning options also has a negative form beginning ‘`-Wno-`’ to turn off warnings; for example, `-Wno-implicit`.

So to disable the unused variable warning, you would pass `-Wno-unused-variable`